# Product of two $4\times4$ elementary matrices has at most $6$ non zero coefficients (True of false)

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

How can I prove that the product of two $4\times4$ elementary matrices has at most $6$ non zero coefficients?

I know that an elementary matrix most likely has $1$'s in it's diagonal and then one other coefficient changed with a random operation.

By trial and error I get that the answer is true, but I can't figure out how to show it.

Comment: Multiplication of elementary matrices is applying row transformations. So for instance, you can get that the product is a matrix which exchanges first row with the second and then adds fourth to the first.

Comment: Which would lead me to at most 6 non zero coefficients, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three types of elementary matrices; row-scaling-, row-switching- and row-adding-matrices. Row-scaling- and row-switching-matrices have $4$ nonzero coefficients, row-adding-matrices have $5$ nonzero coefficients.

Row scaling and row switching don't change the number of nonzero coefficients of the matrix you're multiplying by. So if it is possible to get more than $6$ nonzero coefficients, then it must be done by taking the product of two row-adding-matrices. Can you finish from here?

---

As the question has been answered; a counterexample to the claim is given by the product
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&0\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: You are right. I can get a matrix that has 7 nonzero coefficients by taking the product of two row-adding elementary matrices. Is a counterexample good enough proof to say that this question is false?

Comment: That's right, and yes, a counterexample certainly disproves the statement.